Non-Parametric Two Way Within-Subjects ANOVA
I have a dataset with 4 individuals that are measured twice in each of the 5 groups (so in total 40 observations).



Subject
ID
Group
Value




1
1
A
45


1
2
A
62


1
1
B
70


1
2
B
37


...
...
...
...


4
2
E
50



Now I want to test whether there are significant differences between the groups, taking into account the within-subject correlation (both within and between groups). Due to the extremely small sample size, I would like to use a non-parametric test.
The only option I can think of is to take the mean of the within subject &group values and perform a Friedman test. However, the loss of information in such a small sample seems fatal.

Absolutely do not take the mean and work on that data. Why do you want to use a non-parametric test? Large sample sizes are not a requirement for parametric tests. Were the two measurements per subject done in a pre-post fashion or are they independent?

I want to use a non-parametric test because the sample size is too small to test that the assumptions of parametric tests are met, and there is no literature to suggest an underlying distribution.
The two measurements are taken independently, but there is quite some within-subject variability.

You are probably better off using a parametric test and fixing potential issues with say bootstrapping than using non-parametric tests and modelling it wrong.

With such a small sample size, I think bootstrapping is problematic. Two alternatives that I think might be viable are doing a two-way repeated ANOVA on ranks to reduce the violation of ANOVA assumptions. Or a permutation test, although similarly to bootstrapping, the extremely small sample size might make this infeasible.

No method/approach is going to fix problems associated with small samples. Non-parametric tests require more data to achieve similar confidence because of the lack of assumptions (and bootstrapping makes very few assumptions). Do you have any references of someone doing ANOVA on ranks?

ANOVA on ranks was discussed in the context of a similar problem link

Some implementations of Aligned Ranks Transformation ANOVA allow you to have random effects along with a factorial design.

If I understood you correctly, the implementation in R would look something like this (?) :
model <- art(Value ~ Group + Error(factor(Subject) / (Group * factor(ID))), data = data_melted)
anova(model)
contrast(emmeans(artlm(model, "Group"), ~ Group), method = "pairwise")

In general, I think you don't need to deal with the Error designations, but just use the grammar of lmer.  It appears the code you presented all works, though I don't know if the model designation is correct or not.
